# Does the word for tonsure "neelalu" come from the legend about "Neela Devi" giving her hair to Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu

I was wondering if the word for tonsure "Neelalu" comes from the name of the princess "Neela Devi" because she gave her hair to Lord Vishnu after he was hit on the head and lost some hair. I would love to find a source for the word "Neelalu" (where it comes from) I know that there is a holy hill "Neeladri" named after Neela Devi